# Change ListView Item Background Color based on the value of the Item C# Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, binding, conditional-formatting

I tried looking up the similar problem on the Internet but nothing seems to be like mine.

I have a ListView that displays list of records:

```
    <ListView x:Name="TavoloListView" HasUnevenRows="true" Grid.Row="2" SeparatorColor="Black"  
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTavoloItem, Mode=TwoWay}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid  ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <BoxView x:Name="ItemsBackground" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Color="White" Opacity="0.5"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding TavoloNo}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding CameraNo}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Arrivo, StringFormat='\{0:dd/MM/yy}'}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Partenza, StringFormat='\{0:dd/MM/yy}'}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding PersoneTot}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Bambini, StringFormat='(\{0}\)'}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I need to change `ItemsBackground` `BoxView`'s Color based on the result of comparison of two `Label`s `Arrivo` and `Partenza`.
Basically, on the page there is `DatePicker` named `MainDatePicker`.
I want to compare the records' `Arrivo` and `Partenza` Date Values with the `MainDatePicker.Date`. If `Arrivo == MainDatePicker.Date` I want to change the `ItemsBackground` `BoxView`'s Color to Green. If `Partenza` matches the `MainDatePicker.Date` the `ItemsBackground` `BoxView`'s Color should be Red.

If none of the above is true, the color remains white.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

you can set in side listViewBox colour like this
`

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding BindListViewData}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <BoxView>
                                    <BoxView.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger TargetType="BoxView" Binding="{Binding BindBoolValueFromModel}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger TargetType="BoxView" Binding="{Binding BindBoolValueFromModel}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </BoxView.Triggers>
                                </BoxView>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Add new property in your SelectedTavoloItem, named for example `color` and when you initialize data source for `TavoloListView` just verify your condition

```
public void UpdateDataSourceForLIst()
{

List<SelectedTavoloItem> newListData=new List<SelectedTavoloItem>();
foreach(var item in DataSourceForList)
{
    if(Arrivo == MainDatePicker.Date)
    {
      item.color=green;
      newListData.Add(item);
    }else{
      item.color=red;
      newListData.Add(item);
    }

 }
DataSourceForList=newListData;
}
```

and when you bind list add this code in your box for background:

```
`<BoxView 
   x:Name="ItemsBackground" 
   Grid.Column="0" 
   Grid.ColumnSpan="6" 
   Color="{Binding color}" ////  bind new created property 
   Opacity="0.5"/>`
```

Comment: Why do you use "selected"? Will it apply to whole list? (The color must be verified on whole list, not the selected item only)

Comment: Well I renew the whole list by checking your condition and then according to it assign to each element the color that must have it

Comment: the method I gave an example must be executed before TavoloListView.ItemsSource = DataSourceForList;

Comment: Yeas. Sounds good. What I came with in the meantime was to create a list of my Tavolo records, create new list of type Tavolo2(with color), add original parameters to new object, add last color parameter based on the result, add object to new list and bind listviee to new list.